# NMR fid data opener for ubuntu

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know a good application for an NMR's .fid data.
I'm trying to import my NMR spectra into matlab but I have to convert it to something matlab can actually read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NMRPipe which is an extensive software system for processing, analyzing, and exploiting NMR spectroscopic data. An NMRPipe installation also provides the applications NMRDraw, NMRWish, TALOS+, SPARTA+, DYNAMO, DC, MFR, ACME, and others.

[Further readings and download](http://spin.niddk.nih.gov/NMRPipe/)

Also check this [site](http://www.linux4chemistry.info/). you can find a list of mre than 20 apps for your demand.